# Convert html tag using sed

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed

I have a tag such as the following:

```
<div style="position:absolute;opacity:0.5" class="header">Home</div>
```

(there may or may not be  a style or other attribute) and using sed I need to convert it to a span where the id of the span is the class of the div:

```
<span style="position:absolute;opacity:0.5" id="header">Home</span>
```

I know how to do this in PHP but unfortunately my Linux is lacking :).
The regex to find the eligible DIVs is something along:

```
#<div .* id=(.*)>.*</div>#
```

but I don't know how to write the replacement part, mainly because I need to keep the content between the div tag name and the id. It's 4:45 am so that may have something to do with it as well :p.

I'd appreciate any help on this, thank you.

Comment: `sed 's/div/span/g;s/id/class/g'`

Comment: `sed` might be the wrong tool for that (e.g. because attributes of tags could sit on different lines). Perhaps XSLT might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Using sed, and if you want more specific handling:

```
sed '/<div/{s/<div /<span /;s/ class *=/ id =/;s!</div!</span!}' input
```

still, this assumes start and close tags are on the same line, and there is a single div tag on that line. Also it assumes that the class attribute is the only one on that line.

A more strict command is:

```
sed 's!<div\([^>]*\) class *= *\([^>]*\)>\([^<]*\)</div>!<span\1 id=\2>\3</span>!g' input
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding single line tag, and it appears all the tags are indeed on one line. Well done. Will test and update shortly.

Comment: I'm not understanding the syntax of the first example you posted. I thought you'd need to precede your patterns with the letter s, and then end it with the letter g (to match all).

Comment: In the first one, first you match `<div`. This is not substitute so does not need `s`. Then the block starting with `{` is executed when `<div` matched. In the block, substitute (`s`) `<div` with `<span` and `class` with `id`. There is no global match because the first one assume one div tag per line.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/div/span/;s/id/class/' foo.html
```

Will output

```
<span style="position:absolute;opacity:0.5" class="header">Home</div>
```

Where `foo.html` is your document

### **PAY ATTENTION**

This will replace only the first uccurence of `div` and `id`. If you want to replace all, you have to add "g" char at the end of each substitution pattern, like `s/div/span/g`

And, not less important, if you want to overwrite your document (so if you want to replace occurence "in place") you have to proced in the following way `sed -ie 's/div/span/;s/id/class/' foo.html`

Last thing: as correcly [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch) says in the comments, maybe sed isn't the best choice

Comment: Might not work as required if the HTML text speaks of class or of span. (Imagine a biology THML text about life span of species).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch you're right, but perreal anwser alredy fix this, so i'm not going to edit :)